# Add description or comment to Labels/Relationships

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to add a description to the Node Labels and Relationships, like adding a comment to the Postgres table columns

```
comment on column session_log.userid is 'The user ID';
comment on column session_log.phonenumber is 'The phone number including the area code';
```

This is to document some metadata about the graph. I have looked around and didn't find anything yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have that kind of meta capability.

You could create your own :MetaRel and :MetaLabel nodes and add in the type/label name and a description property.